# React native firebase otp is sending url instead of app name

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Hey i have implemented firebase phone authentication in which i want to detect otp automatically but i am not getting hash in the sms maybe due to longer app name or something else so basically i want to display my app name and hash instead of url. I'm using recaptcha verification because Android device verification api is deprecated.

I'm getting this sms

303231 is your verification code for app-e.firebaseapp.com.

i want to display my app name and hash instead of url.